# What are the pitfalls of my method of sending data between objects?

Tags: java, oop

I'm working out the layout of a game project, and have gotten down a few concrete ideas for the implementation of the "abstract game world".

In this game world everything is represented as a GameObject (vehicles, units, particle effects, ..). I want to keep these objects isolated so that there do not exist any dependencies between them at runtime.

To accomplish this, I let objects request IDs of other objects so that they can send messages to each other, which get delivered to the object with that ID.

The problem I have to tackle is to have a method for requesting data from other objects. For example whether a vehicle currently has a driver. I've considered a few methods for doing this, but by far the closest I have come is a special kind of message where the sender sends a special message to the other object, where the receiving object is expected to place the requested data inside that object.

Here's a "stub" I've written to illustrate how the object would work:

```
public class DataRequestMessage extends Message {
    public final RequestedDataType dataType;
    private boolean requestedDataReceived = false;
    private String stringValue;

    public DataRequestMessage(MessageType type, RequestedDataType dataType) {
        super(type);
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public void setString(String value) {
        if(requestedDataReceived) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The content of the data request object has already been set");
        }
        if(dataType != RequestedDataType.String) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Data type object expects a value of type " + dataType + ", but received one of type String.");
        }
        requestedDataReceived = true;
        this.stringValue = value;
    }

    public String getString() {
        if(dataType != RequestedDataType.String) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This data type object has type " + dataType + ", and can therefore not return a String value.");
        }
        return stringValue;
    }
}
```

As you can see it'll become a mine field when the object isn't used as intended. However, I'm still concerned about that an object expects another object to do something, giving a dependency between the two.

Is this method a good way to request arbitrary data from other objects? Or is expecting another function to perform an operation on a supplied object always a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple notes that may be relevant to you:

- what you are implementing is already an established design known as the Actor model. It seems advisable to at least study what an existing system can do for you before rolling your own;
- you are basically relinquishing Java's static type safety and doing all checking at runtime, as in a dynamic language. Yes, it achieves decoupling, but it necessarily means more runtime errors. The errors are trivial to track down and fix, though; this is why people don't turn their backs at dynamic languages;
- I would advise making the datatype validation a feature of your framework (or existing, if you find a suitable one); separate that concern from the actual message passing.

This **may** be an opportunity for you to learn another JVM-based language which will make all this easier to handle. Scala has an Actor model implemented, with a lot less boilerplate needed than in Java. Another excellent choice would be Clojure.

Comment: I really like the idea of your final point. Though I'd still have to find a way to request various types of data from a "standardized" object without spamming functions for every single data type, possibly ending up with a very similar kind of object. I know about scala and clojure, but I'm not really sure whether they'll be fast enough to handle the required performance for pumping out 60 frames per second.

Comment: Both Scala and Clojure can be as fast as regular Java, but you do need to know how to write performant code (just as in Java). I have extensive experience with top-performant Clojure code dealing with information retrieval and bulk data importing+validation so I can attest to its performance first-hand.